# Post user activity of my site on his facebook profile

Tags: facebook

I am looking for ways that when member of my site post some update(like posting a picture) etc then it could also be published on his facebook profile. How could it be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I believe you are after is how to invoke [stream.publish](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish) from the client side, for which you'd use [FB.ui()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui)