# How to Update Users Activity Through Facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

When I start using an app on Facebook, the app shows "10K people using this app", but before to do that I need to "subscribe" to that app (click a button telling me that I'm going to be using that app) How do I do that with my own app, so I can keep track of the amount of users using it?

Besides, when someone starts using my app (an online magazine) I want to update their activity with something like "John Doe is Reading < Name of the App >"

What elements of the Facebook API do I need to achieve such behaviors?

Comment: Are you asking how to promote your application?

Comment: Out of curiousity, does Facebook advertise that they have real-time statistic updates? You may just need to wait a little bit of time.

Comment: @Lix. No, I'm not asking how to promote my app. I've been in this site long enough to know that this is not that kind of place, and I'm not that kind of user. Feel free to browse the nature of my other questions.
Care to remove the Downvote? 

GlaciesofPacis even though they might not have real-time statistics updates, I'd still like to be able to update my users'activity.

Comment: @AlanChavez - I'd be careful. The URI's to your application and the canvas aren't relevant to the programming question, so I can see where Lix is coming from regarding promotion.

Comment: @AlanChavez - Regarding your other question, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572249/post-user-activity-of-my-site-on-his-facebook-profile

Comment: I thought they might be relevant, but I already removed them.

Comment: @GlaciesofPacis I saw that question before asking, but Facebook Developers states that such method are in the process of being deprecated, I think there's no need to start using something about to be deprecated in a fresh new project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "number of people using this app" statistic is added by Facebook automatically to the app authentication dialog. If you want to show it in your app (manually), you can make a call to `/{your_app_id}` and use the `weekly_active_users` or `monthly_active_users` count.

As for the activity, Facebook automatically posts "User is using App". You won't be able to do "User is reading app" as the page needs to be a object-type that accepts 'read'. 'Read' would only work if you are reading a blog, article, etc.

If you are interested in pursuing it anyway, you need the `publish_actions` permission and you need to register the `read` action in the App Settings. The facebook documentation has everything you need to get started.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, a starting point. Thanks so much for your help.